# Can I draw with antialiasing on canvas?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, antialiasing

Can I draw with anti-aliasing on canvas?

I need my circles and line have smooth edges.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Drawing operations want `Paint`. In this `Paint` you set `Paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)`

Comment: you can use `mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);` instead, as Arun Chettoor suggested

Answer (score 30):

Check this out. It fairly uses smooth edges..
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html

The paint properties needed to get anti-aliasing is :

```
     mPaint = new Paint();
     mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

For drawing use:

```
     mPath = new Path();
     mPath.reset();
     mPath.moveTo(x, y);//can be used where to trigger the path
```

onDraw method should contain:

```
     canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

Declare the mPath and mPaint as global.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` in Paint constructor `Paint(int)`
. The `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` flag enables antialiasing when drawing. Enabling this flag will cause all draw operations that support antialiasing to use it.

Or you can set this flag later using **`setFlags(int)`** method

**Example implementation In Kotlin:**

```
 //Paint
private var indicatorPaint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    isAntiAlias = true
    color = fillColor
    strokeWidth = lineThickness.toFloat()
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
}
```