# Arc on canvas has no antialiasing

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want to draw two colored circle on canvas. Everything is right but the circle isn't smooth.
This is the effect:

[image: This is the effect]

And this is code:

```
private void drawCircle(Canvas c)
{
    RectF oval = new RectF(20, 20, 100, 100);

    c.drawArc(oval, -90, 180, false, getPaintWithColor(R.color.background));
    c.drawArc(oval, 90, 180, false, getPaintWithColor(R.color.font_grey));
}

private Paint getPaintWithColor(int colorId){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(colorId));

    return paint;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
```

See in [Can I draw with antialiasing on canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465191/can-i-draw-with-antialiasing-on-canvas)

Comment: I tried both this solution as well as `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)` (separately and together) and it makes no difference on my `SweepGradient`. Any other ideas?