# How to smooth canvas drawing in Android?

Tags: android-canvas, smoothing

I'm using `Canvas` for drawing in my Android application. But the result has bad quality (see the picture)[image: the result]

[image: scaled]

So, canvas drawing don't draw additional pixels with more dark color between "stairs pixels" for smoothing.
Like this
[image: smoothing]

But I'm interesting how to do it.
Are there some preferences or methods for smoothing the picture? Thanx!

**Edited:** I've founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465191/can-i-draw-with-antialiasing-on-canvas)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled would this be what you're looking for?

Comment: 1) Is it applicable to Android? 2)How professional designers solve this problem, may be without canvas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ANTI-ALIAS flag for drawing smooth edges.

```
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
//or
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setAntiAlias(true);
```